# how to read File line by line and store data in separate arrays

Tags: c++, filestream

How to read a file line by line and store data in a separate array like all the names in one array and marks in another array?

My text file is the following:

```
SARA,DS,A,4
GHANIA,CS,D,3
SIDRA,SE,C,4
JAMIL,AI,A,6
FATIMA,CS,C,4
KOMAL,CS,B,4
FIZA,SE,A,9
ZARA,SE,A,4
HANII,CS,B,4
FOZIA,SE,C,7
```

My code (below) only outputs the first name from the list:

```cpp
void storeData(string studentRecords)
{

    string sData;
    ifstream recordFile(studentRecords);
    if (recordFile)
    {
        getline(recordFile, sData, ',');
        cout << sData;
    }
}
```

How to store the names as well as the marks in 2 distinct arrays?

Comment: Can you format your text file. What are the different columns that it have and their meaning, for example the first column represent the first name, second column represent last name etc? The input text file that you have given in your question is not formatted correctly. Can you format it correctly. Also, what output do you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {

  std::vector<std::string> data;
  std::fstream file("temp.txt", std::ios::in);
  std::string line;

  while (!file.eof()) {
    std::getline(file, line);
    line = line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(","));
    std::cout << line << "\n";
    data.push_back(line);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And use `vectors` instead of `array`.

Comment: yes but this way it'll print everything if only want to extract names like SARA,GHANIA,SIDRA etc. how can i do that?? @LinuxGeek